# Importance of Bhajan in Bhakti Yoga?

Tags: bhakti

Bhakti yog is the way of life i.e. one should always be devoted towards god.

I want to know what is the importance of Bhajans in Bhakti Yoga. In ancient past , most probably Bhajans didn't exist as I don't find any bhajans in sanskrit. Bhajans were introduced in medieval period.

But in today's times bhajans are very important element of practising bhakti yoga .

I want to know are what is the importance of Bhajans in bhakti yoga ?